# Accumulating column in a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a fairly complex query (it takes about 30 seconds to execute) that returns me the following dataset:

```
 Month     Buy     Sell
2010/10     1        2
2010/11     1        3
2010/12     2        5
```

And here's the query:

```
select month, avg(buy) [buy], avg(sell) [sell] from products group by month order by month
```

Now I want to add two Accumulated Columns and the expected resultset is the following:

```
 Month   Ac. Buy   Ac. Sell
2010/10     1          2
2010/11     2          5
2010/12     4          10
```

I'm trying to use this query

```
select 
distinct x.month
,(select SUM(buy) from products where month <= x.month) [Ac Buy]
,(select SUM(sell) from products where month <= x.month) [Ac Sell]
from products X
order by x.month
```

But that takes way too long!

Is there any way to do this faster?

I'm using a MS SQL 2008 Server, but my compability level is set to 80 (like MSSQL 2000, and I can't change that). So I feel like I'm driving a Ferrari using only the 1st gear. );

Comment: How big is the returned dataset from the first query without the running total? Also what is the datatype of the `Month` column?

Comment: Try a Google search for "sqlserver running sum"

Comment: Monht is a varchar column, but if datetime makes it faster, I'll go for it.

the first query return only 13 rows, but the raw table has nearly 2MM records. I'm using the group by to have somehing like a cash flow.

Comment: Andomar, the 'runnning sum' executes a subquery for each row, just like I'm doing today, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 13 rows I would just materialise the intermediate results into a table variable then do a triangular join on that.

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
Month char(7) PRIMARY KEY,
Buy int,
Sell int
)

INSERT INTO @Results /*Your select query goes here*/
SELECT '2010/10',1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT '2010/11',1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT '2010/12',2,5

SELECT R1.Month,
       R1.Buy,
       R1.Sell,
       SUM (R2.Sell)AS AcSell,
       SUM (R2.Buy) AS AcBuy 
FROM @Results R1
JOIN @Results R2 ON R2.Month <= R1.Month
GROUP BY R1.Month,
       R1.Buy,
       R1.Sell
```

Comment: Thanks Martin!!

With your solution, the basic query takes 00:27, and the final result 1:29. Most of this time is inserting data to the @Results.

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at this, I think you might benefit from a CTE (Assuming you can use those with Com Level set to 80....)

Start with a CTE which gathers your original data, and then join the cte results to itself to be able to sum the averages:

```
;with productsCTE
as
(
  -- Original query!
  select month, AVG(buy) buy, AVG(sell) sell 
  from products 
  group by mnth 
)
select 
    p1.month,
    p1.buy,
    SUM(p2.buy) sumavgbuy,
    p1.sell,
    SUM(p2.sell) sumavgsell
from productsCTE p1
inner join productsCTE p2 on p2.month <= p1.month
group by p1.month,p1.buy,p1.sell
```

Comment: CTEs can be simulated with Views or derived tables in SQL Server 2000 but they **don't** get materialised up front so a self join will most likely end up doing the expensive aggregation twice.

Comment: Thanks Jamien!! With your solution, the basic query takes 00:27, and the final result 1:47. Very close to Martin's solution. I'm accepting his answer 'cause he answered 1st.

Comment: @vbandrade - That's interesting and completely contradicts my earlier comment! Does SQL Server add a spool to the plan in this case?